# What is the difference between two statements-

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logic

What is the difference between two statements-

$(a)$.A pair of divergent sequences $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ **such that**  $(s_n+t_n)$ is convergent.

$(b)$.A pair of divergent sequences $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ **with**  $(s_n+t_n)$ is convergent

Comment: I think there is no difference. BTW, with .... being convergent...

Comment: No difference.  Except the second one shouldn't have the "is"; it should just be "with $s_n + s_t$" convergent.  (or "being convergent").  But they both are absolute the same: $s_n, t_n$ are each divergent, while $s_n + t_n$ is convergent.

Comment: These aren't statements.

Comment: @amsmath true.  And the second has an english grammar error.  But as phrases.... I think they are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, sure. I just wanted to mention this.

Comment: This question was asked in my quiz.Exact question is -Give a suitable example of each of the  following-$(a)$.A pair of divergent sequences $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ **such that**  $(s_n+t_n)$ is convergent.

$(b)$.A pair of divergent sequences $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ **with**  $(s_n+t_n)$ is convergent

Comment: @fleablood Thanks. English is not my mother tongue, but I felt there was something wrong with the second sentence. Is it better if one removes 'is' ?

Comment: For english, yes.  For math.... well, people will know what you mean and forgive your poor english.  But the two phrases mean the same.

Comment: I'm perplexed by the question.  I wonder if the text that asked is familiar with English because I don't see a difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Phrase (b) is ungrammatical and does not make sense in standard mathematical English.  In particular, you can't put a finite clause after the preposition with as in "with $(s_n+t_n)$ is convergent".

It would instead be grammatically correct to omit the word "is" and say simply "with $(s_n+t_n)$ convergent" (or to replace "is" with the gerund "being").  However, this does not create any difference in meaning: "a pair of divergent sequences $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ such that $(s_n+t_n)$ is convergent" means exactly the same thing as "a pair of divergent sequences $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ with $(s_n+t_n)$ convergent".